# if statement ignored c

Tags: c, if-statement

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    float a;
    float b;
    float c;

    printf("this program will solve you any equation from this type: ax^2+bx+c=0.\n");
    printf("First of all enter a, b and c:\n");
    printf("a:"); scanf("%f", &a);
    printf("b:"); scanf("%f", &b);
    printf("c:"); scanf("%f", &c); 

    if (a==0){
        printf("now your equation is:\n");
        printf("%.1fx+", b); printf("%.1f=0\n", c);
        float x3 = -c/b;
        printf("the solution for this equation is: %f", x3);
    }
    else{
    printf("now your equation is:\n");
    printf("%.1fx^2+", a); printf("%.1fx+", b); printf("%.1f=0\n", c);

    float d = b*b-4*a*c;
    printf("yy");

    float x1;
    float x2;

    if(d > 0){
        printf("delta is greater than 0! the equation have 2 solutions!\n");
        float x1 = (-b+sqrt(d))/(2*a);
        float x2 = (-b-sqrt(d))/(2*a);
        printf("the first solution is: %.2f\n", x1);
        printf("the second solution is: %.2f\n", x2);
    }

    else if (d == 0)
    {
        printf("delta equals 0 the equation have a doubled solution!\n");
        float x1 = -b / 2*a;
        printf("the doubled solution is: %f", x1);
    }

    else if (d < 0)
    {
        printf("delta is less than 0! the equation have no solutions in R :(");
    }

    }
    return 0;   
}
```

it works perfectly when i run it in vs code terminal thing but when i open the batch file it exits after entering the value of c
edit: the code i posted is only the start and the remaining code is 100% correct because i test it many times in terminal in vs code and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is correctly executed. When you open the batch file, the program reaches the end at the `return 0` istruction (immediatly after you enter `c`). This operation is so fast that apparently is invisible, but the program is executed correctly. The reason why you can see it into the terminal, is because the terminal doesn't clear the prints.